# How can I set up my computer to convert ae to æ, oe to œ and !? to ‽ on the fly?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

I understand some languages do something like this where several words/letters are *combined automatically* as they are typed, eg Arabic.

I also know you can create your own keyboard language layouts for Windows, I've done so, however this functionality seems limited to simply binding keys to other keys and creating extra ctrl+shift combinations. (Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator)

I'm a software developer so I'm not shy of getting into code if needs be but I have no idea where to start, I'd bet something like this exists already. I still want to keep my UK English keyboard layout but with these additions. And yes, this is for novelty purposes.

Answer (score 1):

> but I have no idea where to start, I'd bet something like this exists already.

And you have won the bet!
The solution you are looking for is called a [`global keyboard hook`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264/KeyBoard-Hooks).

If you can programming C#, [here is an example how to do it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook).

I have wrote such hooks former in C but this is not necessary nowadays, with C# you can get it as well.

The working of such a hook is pretty simple: your program get ALL keyboard events BEFORE they will take place!
So you can say for example "if I get an 'a' and 'e' I write instead 'æ' or whatever", you can "map" the trapped characters.

> Hooks are one of the most powerful features of Windows. We can hooks
>   to trap all the events in the Windows environment.
>
> In the Microsoft® Windows™ operating system, a hook is a mechanism by
>   which a function can intercept events (messages, mouse actions,
>   keystrokes) before they reach an application. The function can act on
>   events and, in some cases, modify or discard them. Functions that
>   receive events are called filter functions and are classified
>   according to the type of event they intercept. For example, a filter
>   function might want to receive all keyboard or mouse events. For
>   Windows to call a filter function, the filter function must be
>   installed — that is, attached to a Windows hook (for example, to a
>   keyboard hook). Attaching one or more filter functions to a hook is
>   known as setting a hook. If a hook has more than one filter function
>   attached, Windows maintains a chain of filter functions. The most
>   recently installed function is at the beginning of the chain, and the
>   least recently installed function is at the end.
>
> To maintain and access filter functions, applications use the
>   **SetWindowsHookEx** and the **UnhookWindowsHookEx** functions.